# In django templates how to iterate a variable from one index to another ?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want iterate a variable in Django template but not fully.

Example:

```
{% for service in services %}
    <li><a href=""> {{service.serviceName}} </a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

The above code will iterate through all the items. But I want to iterate the services from 0-9 then 10-18 , 19-27 and so on ..

How can I do this ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice):

```
{% for service in services|slice:"0:9" %}
```

Create an outer loop to separate to sections by indices. You may be able to pre-slice the lists when you pass them to the template, so that's an option as well (depends on your use case...).